# Xcode does not open any project

Tags: macos, xcode

My Xcode can not open any project. I tried to reinstall Xcode and deleted all the files related to it to no avail.

This also occurs when I create a brand new project; I can neither work on it nor open it.

My system:

- M1 MacBook Pro
- macOS Monterey 12.5.1
- Xcode 13.4.1

Comment: When you say "deleted all the files related to it", what do you mean? Do you mean the Developer folder in the User library, or something else? Also, what exactly happens: does the app icon bounce? Do you get a crash log? Have you tried opening it in Safe Boot mode, or in a brand new user account?

Comment: I follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53575585/14973424 to clear all the settings. Actually the app icon does not bounce. I only get the window to choose a project after that I only see my desktop if I try to select or create a new project, Xcode is open because I see it from the app menu. I have not yet tried to open it in safe boot mode or with a new user

Comment: Did you find the solution for that?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with iCloud because it was uploading the folder to the cloud. I simply added the .nosync extension to the folder so as to avoid uploading @AlikhanAlashybay